# How to get ID from the GridView in GridView_RowDeleting event using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to delete one particular row in Gridview. So I need ID, How can I get the ID of the row in GridView_RowDeleting Event?

Here is the column list of the GridView,

```
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No." ControlStyle-Width="100%" ItemStyle-Width="30px">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblSrno" runat="server" Text=''
        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
    <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDrawingID" Text=''
        <%# Bind("DrawingID")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="CustDrawingNbr" HeaderText="Customer Drawing No." />
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ControlStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" Width="100px" Enabled="false">
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
  </asp:TemplateField>

  <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDrawingPGMAStatusID" Text=''
        <%# Bind("StatusID")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDrawingPGMAID" Text=''
        <%# Bind("PGMAID")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
      ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:CommandField>
</Columns>
```

Here I fill one datatable with this GridView.
The DataTable Columns are DrawingID, CustDrawingNbr, JobOrderID, StatusID, PGMAID, SeqNo.
So I want to get the DrawingID when I click the Delete button.

So far,
        I have tried the following things. But nothing has given the desired result.

> 1. Label lblDraw = (Label)gvApplicablePGMASearch.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("lblDrawingID");
>      int drawid = Convert.ToInt32(lblDraw.Text);
> 2. string drawid = gvApplicablePGMASearch.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
> 3. string id = gvApplicablePGMASearch.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();

But none of the above has not given the desired result.

Comment: It seems to me that id should come with 'Delete' event..

Comment: @Bugai. I cant get u. Ellaborate please.

Comment: Why are you using all those Labels inside TemplateFields, why not just use a asp:BoundField and set the DataField? And if you're just using them for hidden ID's, you might prefer instead to just list the ID's in the DataKeyNames, e.g. DataKeyNames="DrawingID,StatusID,PGMAID".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx

You can determine the index of the row that was clicked. Once you've got that index, access the DataKey for that item.

```
DrawingID = gvResults.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value
```

**EDIT** if you have multiple DataKeyNames then it would be like this

```
DrawingID = gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Item("DrawingID").ToString()
```

Just make sure you've set the DataKeyNames set on the gridview and this should work.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="DrawingID">
```

Comment: @NickG You're probably right, this is a nearly-six-year-old answer and I was probably writing VB then haha.

Comment: Well the comment you're replying to is 2 years old :)